# Is there a way to pass the verbose flag for Fastlane Pilot in a lane?

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-pilot

I'm debugging my fastlane actions and lanes to understand if and how to make it faster, but have not found a way to pass the verbose flag to pilot action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pass `verbose: true` to the pilot action.

For example

```
pilot(
    username: my_user_name,
    app_identifier: app_identifier,
    ipa: "path/to/ipa_name.ipa",
    verbose: true
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not tryied but maybe there exist a parameter `pilot(verbose: true)`

But as a workaround, you could call pilot with sh inside your lane

`sh("pilot --verbose -Morearguments")`